# C++ Declare managed type in native code

Tags: variables, c++-cli, native, managed

I need to know how do I declare a managed type inside native code?

Like: I have a ref `class Editor` in `Editor.h`

In native code(main.cpp):

```
Editor^ MainEditor;
```

But it gives me the following:

```
MainEditor' : global or static variable may not have managed type 'Cube3D::Editor ^'
```

I've tried to make it inside a container but I still need to declare it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that directly.  The issue is that the managed object will be moved by the garbage collector, and purely native code can't handle that.

Here's what is allowed:

- Members of managed types must be compiled with `/clr` to produce managed code.  This can use both managed and native types implemented with both managed and native code.
- Members of native types and namespaces can be compiled with `/clr` to produce managed code.  This can use both managed and native types implemented with both managed and native code.
- Members of native types and namespaces can be compiled without `/clr` to produce native code.  This can use only native types, but the types used can be implemented by either managed or native code.
- It's even possible for some members of a native type to be implemented in native code and other members of the same type to be implemented in managed code.

So, you need a layer in between your native code and your managed type, this in-between layer will be a native type implemented with managed code.

Of course, `#pragma managed` can be used interchangeably with `/clr`, for finer control.

Answer (score 1):

As the error states you can't have a managed type at global or static level.

You've declared it right for using it inside a method.  For storing it inside a native class, you'll want to use gcroot.